# Sign in Google - Customize button appearance

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I use the following code to authenticate a user on my website:

```
function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
  console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);

window.onload = function() {
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: "XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  callback: handleCredentialResponse
});
google.accounts.id.renderButton(
 document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
 { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
);

<div id="buttonDiv"></div>
```

But I need to customize the button with the design of my site...

Is it possible to create my own button like this ?

```
<button type="button" onclick="googleLogin();">Connection with Google</button>
```

And with the onlick I can connect. I tested several variants but it does'nt work, the initialization does'nt happen...

how i can customize the button keeping the current code (or just modifying it a bit) ?

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: You can probably make their button and your own custom button, hide their button with `display: none`, then onclick of your button call `.click()` on theirs

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see more or less what you are saying, but you would have an example to give me, because I don't really see how to call their button by clicking on mine?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, probably there is no other way to modify the button style other than using `renderButton` options or just simply CSS.

But there is another option, there is a 'second' API. Afaik, that JS API is considered outdated and Google wants you to use the second one.

So it's [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in?hl=en) about integrating it into an app, and [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button?hl=en) about customizing the button itself.

Comment: As much as possible I will prefer to go on the new version! The solution you proposed to me, I had already tried anyway, but after the connection, I always have an error Object { error: "popup_closed_by_user" } 
this error is probably because I have a new client ID. So anyway, I have no choice to use the new method...